# sqlite3 - how to use with C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm finding several sources of example code (such as that found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html)) that suggest that including  will allow the library to be used. It doesn't seem to work for me. What is the right way to start a project using sqlite in C++?

The following error is what I'm getting back:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
  _main in ccjxXmWk.o
 "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
  _main in ccjxXmWk.o
 "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
  _main in ccjxXmWk.o
 "_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
  _main in ccjxXmWk.o
 "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
  _main in ccjxXmWk.o
```

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work for me." - more precisely?

Comment: The following error: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      _main in ccjxXmWk.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _main in ccjxXmWk.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      _main in ccjxXmWk.o
  "_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
      _main in ccjxXmWk.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccjxXmWk.o`

Excuse the mess.

Comment: you have to link against libsqlite3. (Google the linker error, really. That's how I learned all this.)

Comment: What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Let me quote myself. "Google the linker error, really" - and the solutions arise out of darkness.

Comment: Linking with -lsqlite3 is what I had to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the amalgamation (the `sqlite3.c` file) in your project (and ensure that it's compiled as C, not C++).

Alternatively, link with the SQLite library.

Comment: Linking to the SQLite library (-lsqlite3 to be precise) is what I had to do.